# How to send track1 and track 2 data of EMV to payment gateway in C?

Tags: c, payment, gateway, point-of-sale, emv

Currently I am developing a POS application for my company. I have already extracted the EMV Card data (Chip and Mag).
Now I wish to send these details of track1 and track2 data to the payment gateway to complete the transaction.

What I know till now is -

-I will need to integrate payment gateways api into my code.

-The customer will swipe his magnetic card on the terminal.

-All the details will be captured.

-These details are sent to gateway through the payment gateway api.

-The customer will be asked to insert his PIN only.

-and the transaction gets completed.

I have been through some documents already which tell me to put this data into an XML file and then wrap it into SOAP format. But this is easily possible for languages such as JAVA, Python, .NET C++ and C#.

The POS device that I am using is VEGA-3000. The SDK that was provided with it is in C.

I looked for third party libraries in C which could assist me to integrate my application with Gateway but in vain.

So my Question is ;-

(1) Are there any api available in C for payment gateway integration ?

(2) Do i need to talk to payment gateway providers and Banks if they provide such api at this stage of development?

PS- We are interested in Gateway specific to Indian Region.

Answer (score 0):

I have not heard of sending Chip and PIN data through a payment gateway. 
Ideally the terminals are connected to banks and banks connected to payment schemes like Visa/MC and it uses iso8583 message standards.

Comment: We are not trying to send chip and PIN data. My question is regarding the API's if they available in C to do this process of sending transaction related data to payment gateway ?

Comment: what is the format and protocol you are expecting between your host and payment gateway ?

Comment: Yes..It is in iso 8583 format..and i have started working on that..thank you very much for the valuable information.

Answer (score 0):

You did not mentioned which Gateway you will to use...

1) Yes, there are exists API and libraries which can help your C-application to prepare necessary data in proper message format and transfer it to Payment Gateway.

2) Yes, you need to ask your Bank partners to clear the Gateway specific requirement. At least they can provide you the references to the specification they used. Because of wide range of payment terminals and the different payment gateway probably you need to implement the API yourself or ask professionals to prepare/customize API for you.

Depending of your communication Gateway solution it will be different implementation requirements at your POS terminal side. At least you need to use (or implement) Payment Gateway message protocol specification. This communication protocol could be some customization of ISO 8583 Financial messages standards, Field Separated protocol messages, Block messages, or some of modern web-kind solutions which used webservices, SOAP, XML, JSON or even pure HTTP/Headers solutions.

Please clear the Gateway and it's API you able to use before asking C libraries and solutions for your terminal.

Comment: Dear Coder, in stackoverflow project the common "thanks" are the marks Up for the answers. Isn't it?